# Bind multiple values in gonic-gin

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="post" method="post">
            <select name="message" multiple>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit">
</form>
```

How do I get all messages by using [gonic-gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) Bind method?

Comment: Looklike gonic-gin dont support to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Hi the easy way to get values from a select multiple a form html is

```
import "log"
 // ...
func MyHandler(c *gin.Context){
     log.Print( c.Request.Form["message"] )
}
```